# django - template does not exists at /

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I'm starting a new Django project, but straight away I can't set up the correct templates directory path.
this are my settings.py:

```
import os
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I have a very simple view in the project folder:

```
def dashboard(request):

    context = {

    }
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'
    return render(requst, template_name, context)
```

dahsboard.html is located in BASE_DIR/templates/dashboard.html.

Pretty straight forward, but still I get the Error:
*"TemplateDoesNotExist at /
dashboard.html"*

This is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.2
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Presents',
 'Customers',
 'Orders',
 'Users',
 'comuni_italiani',
 'import_export',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/carloc/Projects/natale/src/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/carloc/Projects/natale/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/carloc/Projects/natale/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/carloc/Projects/natale/src/Presents/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/carloc/Projects/natale/src/Customers/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/carloc/Projects/natale/src/Orders/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/carloc/Projects/natale/src/Users/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/carloc/Projects/natale/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/carloc/Projects/natale/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/carloc/Projects/natale/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/carloc/Projects/natale/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/carloc/Projects/natale/src/natale/views.py", line 12, in dashboard
    return render(request, template_name, context)
  File "/home/carloc/Projects/natale/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/carloc/Projects/natale/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/home/carloc/Projects/natale/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: dashboard.html
```

Comment: It must be: `return render(request, template_name, context)`. Otherwise, Can you show full traceback?

Comment: Sorry, I lost that part of the code while copying from the editor. I've updated the post with the trackback as well. Thank you

Comment: You have a type error on : return render(requst...), it should be return render(request...).

Comment: Can you show your project structure ?

Comment: @CarloCogni, as you can see (it does not exist): `/home/carloc/Projects/natale/src/templates/dashboard.html (Source does not exist)`. Move your template to this directory **`/home/carloc/Projects/natale/src/templates/`**